# Here Maps - *Keeping* center location on resize

Tags: here-api

We have a Here Map inside a flexbox. When a button is added below the map, the map gets resized (as expected) to be smaller, but as a result the map center (center coordinates on the map) shift. Is there a built-in way to ensure that the map center coordinates don't change on resize?

Ie. Before they'd be at 22.2 (lat), 74.7 (long) but after the move be at 22.3, 74.7. (Note: just example numbers for simplicity. Actually lat / lng  is more along the lines of 22.22327181024894 74.7043131363445.)

I was planning on adding in some logic that detects if the size changes to save the existing coordinates before adding in the button and then resetting the map center to the previous coordinates, but would rather use something built in if possible to prevent the reload.

Also, not sure where exactly to re-apply the center if we do our own solution.

We are using:

```
<script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-service.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-mapevents.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Any advice would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon adding the button and therefore after the container is resized, make sure to call the following instruction:

```
map.getViewPort().resize();
```

However make sure that the resize call is triggered *after* the container is effectively resized

Comment: I don't think this answers my question. My map resizes as expected when its container gets smaller, but my issues is that I want to keep the existing *center coordinates* as the center of the map even after it gets resized. In my case, it gets resized, and then the center coordinates move more north because the map gets "shorter".

Comment: I see, amended the answer. In short, make sure to call `map.getViewPort().resize()` in a place after the container resize is finished, and the map center will be properly updated

Comment: I'm not sure if the edit answers it either? The map is getting resized after the button is added, as expected. It becomes smaller. The map center's coordinates, if they were previously at: 
22.25, 74
Move up and become 
22.3, 74, for example because the center was shifted.

I want the coordinate to stay at 22.25, 75 even after the resize.

I can update the question if that makes it more clear

Comment: I think it answers :) You need to call the resize method so that the offset of the map center relatively to the map container, is recomputed after the map container change. One reason it may not work is if the resize is called too early. You may debug or log the container dimensions to check. As a debug trick you can delay the resize by some seconds with `setTimeout(() => map.getViewPort().resize(), 5000)` (delay by 5 seconds)

Comment: Ok, I will give your updated comment a shot. Thanks!